# Property of vector field in a sobolev space

Tags: differential-geometry, sobolev-spaces, vector-bundles, vector-fields, symplectic-geometry

Suppose I have a smooth map $u: \mathbb{R}\times [0,1]\rightarrow TP$ , where $P$ is a symplectic manifold with an almosct complex compactible structure , consider $k>1$, such that $u\in L^2_{k}(\mathbb{R}\times [0,1],P)$ and $u(\tau,i)\subset L_i$ for $i=0,1$ where $L_i$ are lagrangian submanifolds , and that $\lim_{\tau\rightarrow \infty}u(\tau,t)=x\in L_1\cap L_0$ and $\lim_{\tau\rightarrow -\infty}u(\tau,t)=y\in L_1\cap L_0$. Now consider $\xi \in L_{k}^2(\mathbb{R}\times [0,1],P)$ vector fields along $u$ and $\eta \in L_{k-1}^2(\mathbb{R}\times [0,1],P)$

Will it in fact be true that $\int_{0}^1 \langle \xi,\eta\rangle|_{-\infty}^{\infty}dt=0 ?$

I have tried using sobolev inequalities here and see if this would force me to have that $\lim_{\tau \rightarrow \infty}\xi=0$ but I couldn't manage to get anything useful.

If anyone knows another approach to this I would appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have no idea about all the geometric stuff you wrote but no, finite integral does not imply convergence to 0 at infinity, unless you say, know that it actually does converge.

Comment: Is there a sobolev space to where the function can be so that is true ? @CalvinKhor

Comment: Because I have no idea about all your notation, I don’t know what function you are talking about. Can you phrase your question (this last one in comments) in terms of symbols involving the usual $\mathbb R^n$ or subsets thereof

Comment: The notation $\langle \xi,\eta\rangle|_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ implicitly suggests the existence of $\lim_{x \to \infty} \xi(x,t) \eta(x,t)$, for example, which is problematic. Do you assume this a priori? What is your original goal? I have the feeling that you arrived at $\langle \xi,\eta\rangle|_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ by some integrate-by-parts manipulations, and the problem is there.